# Peltier effect Asymmetrical perforance

Tags: electrical-engineering, heat-transfer

When current is injected into a Peltier device/thermo-electric cooler, it heats up, when the current is reversed, it cools down. Why does it takes less time to heat up than to cool down?

Comment: What is your evidence for the asymetrical heating / cooling?

Comment: What temperatures?

Comment: This question comes perilously close to the "hot water freezes faster than cold" flame war.  However, as restated by Olin L., the functionality seems clear.

Comment: @Solar Mike. experiment

Comment: @ JMac. Between 5 and 45oC

Comment: @Sam Why should I - I did not ask the question... I was hoping the OP would have some evidence that could be examined to move the question forward.

Comment: @Sam - your lower temperature - surely it should be lower than that as they are used for cool boxes...

Comment: @SolarMike: Peltier cell as a whole doesn't cool anything - it just heats due to its losses, and MOVES heat from one side to the other. When current it reversed it MOVES heat in the opposite direction. Given the right cooling capacity - radiators, fans, other heat sinks on the "hot" side - it can cool things on the "cold" side. But regardless of that, it heats up, and if heat is not removed, even the "cold" side will be hot.

Comment: @SF so your explanation depends on where you draw the boundaries...

Comment: @SolarMike: No, it explains how the peltier module works. Higher temperature gradient allows better heat dissipation, but that's a role of the radiator. Peltier module only *moves heat*, it doesn't *create cold*. It also *creates heat* on top of that. The heat (sum of moved and created) must be removed by other means - like radiators. Your cool box will be an oven if you put the peltier module inside, instead of mounting it in the wall so that it moves heat from inside to outside. Or if it has no radiator to dissipate that heat.

Comment: ...and the "lower temperature" will be proportional primarily to your heat dissipation capacity. Peltier modules, despite their special properties, still conduct heat like normal solids, so if you let the "hot" side run hot enough, the "cold" side won't be very cold at all.

Comment: Exactly my point about the boundary : you have just placed the module across the boundary : wall so heat is absorbed form the inside and radiated to the outside, which can only happen if the part of the module inside is able to absorb heat (cooler) than its surroundings and if the part of the module outside is warmer than its surroundings.

Comment: @SolarMike: Yes, this is correct - although the cause-and-effect aren't as clear-cut; ability to absorb or emit heat, while proportional to temperature difference, depends on some other factors (surface area, medium exchange, surface emittance and absorbance etc.) As long as the "outer" side can dispose of heat both transmitted and produced, "inner" will keep getting colder. If the outer side of peltier module is much hotter than the surroundings but can't dissipate that heat (say, it's in near-vacuum, has small area and gets heated by sunlight) you won't keep the inner side much colder.

Answer (score 3):

Peltier devices are quite inefficient.  A simple first-order approximation for a Peltier is a perfect heat pump in series with a resistor.  The heat pump moves heat symmetrically proportional to the current, but the resistor always makes heat proportional to the square of the current.

The unavoidable heater in a Peltier device makes it overall better at making heat than cold.